# Module is not imported from the current directory

Tags: python, import, module, importerror, modulenotfounderror

I have the following directory structure:

```
project/
├── src/
│   └── main.py
└── modules/
     ├──__init__.py
     └──futures.py
```

I want to import modules from futures.py into main.py, but I get the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules'

code in `futures.py`:

```
def my_function():
    return 1
```

code in `main.py`:

```
from modules.futures import my_function

print(my_function())
```

I tried writing the following line in `__init__.py`:

```
from futures import *
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using python 3.12 and vs code

Comment: Is `futures` supposed to be a top-level module or a submodule of a `modules` packages? Do note that imports do not navigate directories. `from futures` means "search for a top level module names `futures` on the import path", _not_ "look for `futures.py` in the same source directory".

Comment: @Brian61354270 submodule

Comment: In that case the import you want is `from modules.futures import *`. Just make sure that the `project` directory is being added to the import path somehow (typically, by installing your project to your virtual environment, or relying on it being your CWD).

Comment: @Brian61354270 I have to write in the main.py file

"import modules.futures"?

Comment: If `main.py` is the start script (called from command line or IDE to initially run the program), you have to manipulate `sys.path` to add `project` or `modules` before you can import something from above `src`.

Comment: if you would have `modules` inside `src` (where you have `main.py`) then you could use `from modules.futures import *`. But you have `modules` outside `src` - so  Python doesn't know where is `modules`. You would have to install `modules` using `pip` or you have to add `path/to/project` (not `path/to/modules`) to `sys.path` before `from modules.futures import *`  - something like this: `import sys` , `sys.path.append("/full/path/to/project")`, `from modules.futures import *`

Comment: The linked module is processed by `pytest` which either modifies `sys.path` itself or uses a special mechanism to provide import functionality.